# Remake LINQ request to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'm using EF and LINQ but it's slow.

I want to remake request to clean SQL, but have a problem.

For example, I have this request.

```
var request = await db.Journal.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.userid == userId).Select(x => new Statistic
            {
                DoneAt = x.DoneAt,
                Description = x.Description,
                Procedures = x.Procedures.Select(a => new Procedures
                {
                    Name = a.Name,
                    Time = a.Time
                }).ToList()
            }).ToListAsync();
```

Two related tables Journal and Procedures. One record in Journal has relations with one or many records in Procedures. And it's easy to mapping it with EF. I receiving list of procedures for every record in journal. It's OK.

Next, I'm trying to remake this request to SQL and I'm using Join to receive results in one table. But I receiving a duplicates row when Procedures have more then one row. And it's OK. But it's no conveniently to work with it - need parse it and make it like it was when I use LINQ and EF (every Journal record has a list of procedures).Is there any other way or best practice or just retrieve this data and then convert it to Object?

Comment: is data duplication is your problem?

Comment: If you want to get the plain sql for EF, query `Entity Framework Query Logging` or `Entity Framework Logging`.  You can log the query used to the console. But I fail to understand your exact issue in this question. Can you give us some example data, your query, resulting output, and what your expected output is?

Comment: If `procedures` is a navigation property on `Journal` then I don't think you need that embedded select statement. Probably same goes for the internal `ToList()`

Comment: Perhaps this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your purpose in remaking the query in SQL?

Comment: When I used EF with LINQ request - I received data and converted it to Object where every record in Journal has list of Procedures. When I use SQL I receiving only one table and can't understand how can I get an Object where every record in Journal will have a list of Procedures. I see only one table where journal records and procedures records - all in one places.